# Ubuntu won't boot after install on ssd

Tags: boot, uefi, ssd

Last week I bought  new Acer Laptop which came with a pre-installed Windows 8.1. I replaced the factory 500GB HDD for a Crucial MX100 256GB SSD, after which I used a bootable USB device to install Ubuntu 14.04 onto the SSD. After the installation the laptop reset itself per usual, but after the BIOS screen I got the message *“There is no bootable device”*. After that I booted Ubuntu from the USB drive and used boot repair, during which I got an error somewhere in the process. It gave me this boot script:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8762374/

Bios boot settings: Boot Mode: UEFI, Secure Boot: Enabled, HDD (the Crucial SSD) is first in Boot priority order.

**Laptop specs:**

Acer ES1-311, Intel Celeron CPU N2840, 4 GB DDR3 memory, SSD Crucial MX100

Is there anyone that recognizes the problem from the boot/log? On my previous laptop I had no problem installing and using UBUNTU.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First try turning off Secure Boot. But some systems will only boot an UEFI entry with Windows in the name. See D: in this, you can rename shim or grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789